# Need to replace union in the SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, union

**I have to write a sql query**

For each product, determine how many times it was bought in 2010, if at all.
The result should be tuples of the form (product name, num times). If a product
was not purchased at all in 2010, the second attribute should have a value of 0. 
Don't use a UNION operator.

**I have written the query using UNION but I have to write it without using UNION Operator**

```
SELECT p.product_name , COUNT(p.product_id)
  FROM product p JOIN buys b ON p.product_id = b.product_id
  WHERE b.year = 2010
  GROUP BY p.product_name
UNION
 SELECT p.product_name, 0
  FROM product p JOIN buys b ON p.product_id = b.product_id
  WHERE b.product_id NOT IN (SELECT pr.product_id FROM product pr JOIN buys bu ON pr.product_id = bu.product_id WHERE bu.year = 2010)
  GROUP BY p.product_name;
```

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE product(
  product_id NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  product_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  product_price NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  product_manufacturer VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pr_pk PRIMARY KEY(product_id)
  );

CREATE TABLE customer(
  customer_id NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  customer_age NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT cu_pk PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
  );

CREATE TABLE buys(
  customer_id NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  product_id NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  month NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL,
  day NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL,
  year NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT bu_pk PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, product_id),
  CONSTRAINT bu_fk1 FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id),
  CONSTRAINT bu_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id)
  );
```

Please help.

**EDIT**
I just did the query

```
SELECT p.product_name , COUNT(b.customer_id)
  FROM product p LEFT OUTER JOIN buys b ON p.product_id = b.product_id AND b.year = 2010
  GROUP BY p.product_name;
```

Comment: Hint: use an outer join.

Comment: Thank You I just did it using Left OUTER JOIN.

Comment: You might use Coalesce(Count(b.customer_id),0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the query

```
SELECT p.product_name , COUNT(b.customer_id)
  FROM product p LEFT OUTER JOIN buys b ON p.product_id = b.product_id AND b.year = 2010
  GROUP BY p.product_name;
```